# Installing Clang-7 in Ubuntu 20.04 version

Tags: 20.04, clang

I have problem installing clang-7 in Ubuntu 20.04.
Other version of clang is installed without any problem.
But only clang-7 gives message like this.

```
clang-7 : Depends: libstdc++-5-dev but it is not installable
       Depends: libgcc-5-dev but it is not installable
       Depends: libobjc-5-dev but it is not installable
       Depends: libclang-common-7-dev (= 1:7.1.0~svn353565-1~exp1~20190408084827.60) but 1:7.0.1-12 is to be installed
       Recommends: python
       Recommends: libomp-7-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The message means that the Depends can't be install in Ubuntu 20.04.
In this situation, is there any other method that I can install Clang-7 and use it?

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and try again.

Comment: According to https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/clang-7, `clang-7` does not depend on `libstdc++-5-dev`. Are you using any PPA for clang-7?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)